# Slow performance for deeply nested subquery factoring (CTE)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, benchmarking

This query consists of 16 equal steps.
Every step is doing the same calculation on the same dataset (a single row),
but last steps take too much time for it.

```
with t0 as (select 0 as k from dual)
,t1 as (select k from t0 where k >= (select avg(k) from t0))
,t2 as (select k from t1 where k >= (select avg(k) from t1))
,t3 as (select k from t2 where k >= (select avg(k) from t2))
,t4 as (select k from t3 where k >= (select avg(k) from t3))
,t5 as (select k from t4 where k >= (select avg(k) from t4))
,t6 as (select k from t5 where k >= (select avg(k) from t5))
,t7 as (select k from t6 where k >= (select avg(k) from t6))
,t8 as (select k from t7 where k >= (select avg(k) from t7))
,t9 as (select k from t8 where k >= (select avg(k) from t8))
,t10 as (select k from t9 where k >= (select avg(k) from t9))
,t11 as (select k from t10 where k >= (select avg(k) from t10))
,t12 as (select k from t11 where k >= (select avg(k) from t11)) -- 0.5 sec
,t13 as (select k from t12 where k >= (select avg(k) from t12)) -- 1.3 sec
,t14 as (select k from t13 where k >= (select avg(k) from t13)) -- 4.5 sec
,t15 as (select k from t14 where k >= (select avg(k) from t14)) -- 30 sec
,t16 as (select k from t15 where k >= (select avg(k) from t15)) -- 4 min
select k from t16
```

Subquery t10 completes immediately, but the entire query (t16) requires 4 minutes to complete.

Q1.
**Why** calculation times of identical subqueries on the same data are very different?

Q2.
It looks like a bug as it runs very fast on Oracle 9 and very slow on Oracle 11.
In fact, every select statement with long and complex with-clause would behave the same way.
**Is it a known bug**?  (I don't have access to metalink)
What workaround is recommended?

Q3.
I must write code for Oracle 11 and I must do all my calculations in single select statement.
I can't split my long statement in two separate statements to speed it up.
**Does there exist a hint** in Oracle (or maybe some trick) to make the whole query (t16) be completed in a reasonable time (e.g., within one second)?  I tried to find such one but to no avail.
BTW, execution plan is excellent, and cost behaves as a linear function (not exponential) of number of steps.

Comment: Could it be a difference in the installation? Eg. disk speed, amount of available memory, configuration, etc.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - How many memory is required to operate on datasets of ONE row? )))   The same about disk speed.

Comment: I think I start to understand the query. It's a weird one.

Comment: it 'feels' exponetial, i think that your database is building up a cartasian product of all (even only one row) tables

Comment: sorry, to fast send ... the original statement would be helpful, because i cant see any "where" clause here

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - again sry, I meant, that the statement you show does not make sense - you get '0' as result. With such a construct, there is a good chance, that you found something, a database optimizer dies. What is the idea you have, what do you want to get irl?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger these are not 16 equal steps! with each step you add an additional (temp-)table to your query

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff This is an interesting question and deserves an interesting title.  There are thousands of questions with titles like "Why is this slow?" and most of them are boring.  The current, generic title, is unlikely to attract much attention.  The specific reason I changed the title is because I wanted to reference it years later, but it took me a very long time to find it.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That makes sense.  I don't care if you keep the title I suggested, but it would be helpful to change it to something better.  Maybe "deeply nested subquery factoring (WITH) slow"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1: Seems that there are nothing about calculation time, just bug in optimizer algorithm which make it mad while calculating a best execution plan.

Q2: There are a number of known and fixed bugs in Oracle 11.X.0.X related to optimization of nested queries and query factoring. But it's very hard to find a concrete issue.

Q3: There are two **undocumented** hints: `materialize` and `inline` but no one of them works for me while I tried your example. It's possible that some changes in server configuration or upgrading to 11.2.0.3 may increase limit of nested `with` clauses: for me (on 11.2.0.3 Win7/x86) your example works fine, but increasing number of nested tables to 30 hangs a session.

Workaround may look like this:

```
select k from (
select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t16
  select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t15
    select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t14
      select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t13
        select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t12
          select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t11
            select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t10
              select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t9
                select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t8
                  select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t7
                    select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t6
                      select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t5
                        select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t4
                          select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t3
                            select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( --t2
                              select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from ( -- t1
                                select k, avg(k) over (partition by null) k_avg from (select 0 as k from dual) t0
                              ) where k >= k_avg
                            ) where k >= k_avg
                          ) where k >= k_avg
                        ) where k >= k_avg
                      ) where k >= k_avg
                    ) where k >= k_avg
                  ) where k >= k_avg
                ) where k >= k_avg
              ) where k >= k_avg
            ) where k >= k_avg
          ) where k >= k_avg
        ) where k >= k_avg
      ) where k >= k_avg
    ) where k >= k_avg
  ) where k >= k_avg
) where k >= k_avg
)
```

At least it works for me on nesting level of 30 and produces totally different execution plan with `WINDOW BUFFER` and `VIEW` instead of `LOAD TABLE AS SELECT`, `SORT AGGREGATE` and `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

**Update**

1. Just installed 11.2.0.4 (Win7/32bit) and test it against initial query. Nothing changed in optimizer behavior.
2. There are no possibility to directly affect a CBO behavior, even with use of `inline` (undocumented) or `RULE` (deprecated) hints. May be some Guru knows a some variant, but it's a Top Secret for me (and Google too :-) .
3. Doing things in a one select statement in reasonable time is possible if a main select statement separated into a parts and placed into the function which returns a set of rows (function returning sys_refcursor or strong typed cursor), but it's not a choice if a query constructed at runtime.
4. Workaround with usage of XML is possible, <strike>but this variant looks like removing a tonsil through the ass hole</strike> (sorry):

.

```
select
  extractvalue(column_value,'/t/somevalue') abc
from 
  table(xmlsequence((
    select t2 from (
      select
        t0,
        t1,
        (   
          select xmlagg(
                   xmlelement("t", 
                     xmlelement("k1",extractvalue(t1t.column_value,'/t/k1')), 
                     xmlelement("somevalue", systimestamp))
                  )
          from 
            table(xmlsequence(t0)) t0t, 
            table(xmlsequence(t1)) t1t  
          where 
            extractvalue(t1t.column_value,'/t/k1') >= (
              select avg(extractvalue(t1t.column_value, '/t/k1')) from table(xmlsequence(t1))
            )                                              
            and 
            extractvalue(t0t.column_value,'/t/k2') > 6
        ) t2
      from (
        select
          t0,
          (
            select xmlagg(
                     xmlelement("t", 
                       xmlelement("k1",extractvalue(column_value,'/t/k1')), 
                       xmlelement("somevalue", sysdate))
                    )
            from table(xmlsequence(t0))   
            where 
              extractvalue(column_value,'/t/k1') >= (
                select avg(extractvalue(column_value, '/t/k1')) from table(xmlsequence(t0))
              )
          ) t1
        from (
          select
            xmlagg(xmlelement("t", xmlelement("k1", level), xmlelement("k2", level + 3))) t0
          from dual connect by level < 5
        )
      )
    )
  )))
```

Another thing about a strange code above is that this variant applicable only if `with` data sets didn't have a big number of rows.

Comment: Thanks for your idea about optimizer getting crazy and for the workaround.  Unfortunately, my real-life code is not so simple, and I can't rewrite it using analytical functions.  What is the preferred way to disable (or to switch to another mode) the optimizer, so it would stop being mad, maybe at the cost of some performance degradation of table operations?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff What is the obstacle that prevents rewriting of a query from form using `with` to the form that uses subqueries? Is it possible to post an example which is more close to real situation?

Comment: Dependencies are complex, each `t_i` is involved in 2-3 distinct `t_j` below.  Usual subqueries (as inline views) are used whenever possible, too.

Answer (score 5):

(This is isn't a full answer.  Hopefully the information here will help someone else produce a better answer.)

**Q1:** The optimizer rewrites the query by inlining everything.  The internal statement doubles in size with each new common table expression and the statements quickly grow ginormous.  For example, T15 produces a 3,162,172 character query.

Code to trace the statements:

```
sqlplus user/pass@orcl

alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';

with t0 as (select 0 as k from dual)
,t1 as (select k from t0 where k >= (select avg(k) from t0))
,t2 as (select k from t1 where k >= (select avg(k) from t1))
select k from t2;

exit;


sqlplus user/pass@orcl

alter session set events '10053 trace name context forever, level 1';

with t0 as (select 0 as k from dual)
,t1 as (select k from t0 where k >= (select avg(k) from t0))
,t2 as (select k from t1 where k >= (select avg(k) from t1))
,t3 as (select k from t2 where k >= (select avg(k) from t2))
select k from t3;
exit;
```

If you compare the two trace files there are many differences, but most of them look very minor.  The real difference is in only a single line that comes right after the string: `Stmt: ******* UNPARSED QUERY IS *******`.  Be careful opening the trace files if you trace larger queries.  Not all editors can handle such huge lines.  And the T20 file was 250MB!

SQL from first trace, after formatting:

```
SELECT "T1"."K" "K"
  FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
          FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
         WHERE 0 >= (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1"
 WHERE "T1"."K" >=
       (SELECT AVG("T1"."K") "AVG(K)"
          FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
                  FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
                 WHERE 0 >= (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1")
```

SQL from second trace, after formatting:

```
SELECT "T2"."K" "K"
  FROM (SELECT "T1"."K" "K"
          FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
                  FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
                 WHERE 0 >= (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1"
         WHERE "T1"."K" >=
               (SELECT AVG("T1"."K") "AVG(K)"
                  FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
                          FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
                         WHERE 0 >=
                               (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1")) "T2"
 WHERE "T2"."K" >=
       (SELECT AVG("T2"."K") "AVG(K)"
          FROM (SELECT "T1"."K" "K"
                  FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
                          FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
                         WHERE 0 >=
                               (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)" FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1"
                 WHERE "T1"."K" >=
                       (SELECT AVG("T1"."K") "AVG(K)"
                          FROM (SELECT 0 "K"
                                  FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL"
                                 WHERE 0 >= (SELECT AVG(0) "AVG(K)"
                                               FROM "SYS"."DUAL" "DUAL")) "T1")) "T2")
```

**Q2:** I wouldn't say every "complex" common table expression would behave the same way.  I've seen CTEs that were much larger.  It's only the extreme nesting that seems to be the problem.  I couldn't find any obvious bugs on Oracle Support.

ThinkJet's code looks like a good work around.  Nesting inline views is more common than nesting common table expressions.

**Q3:** There probably is a hint to prevent this behavior, but I'm not sure what it is.  Hopefully by showing the transformed version of the query someone else can guess how to fix it.