# (Oracle) Multiple WITH Clauses Referencing Each Other

Tags: sql, oracle

We are rewriting a SQL script originally containing 6 CREATE/REPLACE VIEW's, because our new app can't create objects in the DB. To rewrite it, we are using the WITH keyword.

The problem is, the original views referenced each other. Will this be allowed in Oracle:

```
with 
  A as (select T1COL from Table1 ...), 
  B as (select NEWCOL from A ...) ,
..
```

Comment: Due to the large amount of code involved it's not feasible to quickly try it. One would hope a quick response wouldn't be too difficult.

Comment: In your example, `B` references `A`, but `A` does *not* refer to `B`.  So why do you say that the views refer to *each other*, implying some sort of circular reference problem?

Comment: "*it's not feasible to try*" - and the accepted answered proved you wrong there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: yes, it is possible.

> Due to the large amount of code involved it's not feasible to quickly try it. One would hope a quick response wouldn't be too difficult

I've prepared a runnable test for you:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/7884

```
WITH 
  a AS ( SELECT 'A' as T1COL FROM dual ),
  b AS ( SELECT * FROM a ),
  c AS ( SELECT * FROM b ),
  d AS ( SELECT * FROM c ),
  e AS ( SELECT * FROM d ),
  f AS ( SELECT * FROM e ),
  g AS ( SELECT * FROM f ),
  h AS ( SELECT * FROM g ),
  i AS ( SELECT * FROM h ),
  j AS ( SELECT * FROM i ),
  k AS ( SELECT * FROM j ),
  l AS ( SELECT * FROM k ),
  m AS ( SELECT * FROM l ),
  n AS ( SELECT * FROM m ),
  o AS ( SELECT * FROM n ),
  p AS ( SELECT * FROM o ),
  q AS ( SELECT * FROM p )  
SELECT * FROM q;
```

Comment: I know this is just a demo but you may want to be careful nesting so many CTEs.  Using this many references can cause performance problems, as discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19797675/409172).